# C user input getting skipped

Tags: c, memory, input, allocation

I wrote a code in C, which utilizes dynamic memory allocation but my input gets skipped second iteration onwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of users :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // char **array = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    char flag[4];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("Does user have middle name? (yes/no) :");
        scanf("%s", flag);
        if (strcmp("yes", flag)==0) {
            char **array = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                array[i] = (char *)malloc(9);
            printf("First name :");
            scanf("%s", array[0]);
            printf("Middle name :");
            scanf("%s", array[1]);
            printf("Last name :");
            scanf("%s", array[2]);
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
                free(array[i]);
            free(array);
        }
        else {
            char **array = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
                array[i] = (char *)malloc(9);
            printf("First name :");
            scanf("%s", array[0]);
            printf("Last name :");
            scanf("%s", array[1]);
            for(int i=0;i<2;i++) 
                free(array[i]);
            free(array);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Here, say I give n=3 and enter "yes". It inputs the first, middle, last name but then skips the next "Does it have a middle name". Why is this happening??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the full and complete input you give to the program when running.

Comment: I also recommend you take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through you code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens in the code.

Comment: I get a segmentation fault immediately after entering the first name and middle name on the first iteration. This would definitely stop it from going a second time around.  Also, you forgot to include string.h and stdio.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    array[i] = (char *)malloc(9);
```

you want to use the index `j`, not `i`:

```
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    array[j] = malloc(9); // Don't cast malloc
```

You are also shadowing `i` in the inner loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    ...
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
```